# Router doesn't have a public ip adress

Tags: iis, vpn, proxy, ip, isp

I have a problem with my ISP where my router gets a different ip adress compared to my external ip adress (the router doesn't have a public ip adress). I previously setup a VPN service with EdgeMax and I host some websites on a server. But sins the ip adresses differ I cannot acces them. I have thought about this a while and I think it could be solved using a reverse proxy server. How should I solve this problem?

Thanks beforehand!
Best regards Max

Comment: That's a common case if your ISP does not want you to expose services to the internet for free. What you thought ("reverse proxy") won't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic DNS service to update your DNS hostname with your new IP every time it changes.

You would then use the hostname to access your services.

If you require a static IP then you will need to discuss your options with your ISP.

Comment: I might have explained the problem a bit wrong, it's not just that the ip addresses differ but the router doesn't have a public ip adress.